# how to get intent when alertbox close?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-alertdialog

What I am doing is sending `Intent` to `MainActivity` from `Listview` the listview item I am displaying in alertbox.

```
holder.txtStore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String value = holder.txtStore.getText().toString();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("restaurant_name", value);
            try {
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "yourActivity is not founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

In `MainActivity` right now I am using button to start `getIntent` but I don't want to use button I just want to start `getIntent` function when alertbox disappear or ya when `MainActivity` start I try to use `onResume` or `onRestart`. But not work for me.

This is my code to call `getIntent` using button:

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(restaurant_name != null ) {
            if (restaurant_name.equals("Romys")) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759), 15.0f));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(26.89553, 75.82842))
                        .title("ROMYS"))
                        .showInfoWindow();


            }
        }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"It was not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) help?

Comment: app crash after clicking on listview

Comment: and show error here mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759), 15.0f));

Comment: @UtkarshSharma   you can get the intent in `onCreate()` of mainActivity and check whether it cames from listview item. e.g by putting a boolean in the listiview litem intent and checking for the boolean availability in main activity. if available, you will know that the intent comes listview item

Answer (score 0):

Use onNewIntent to update MainActivity. Kind of like this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

If you are displaying the alertbox from the MainActivity, consider adding flags to your intent to maintain the activity stack.